# DropCreateDataBaseAlways is not working when working with multiple db schemas with Entity Framework 6 Code First

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

After watching the "Enhancements to Code First Migrations: Using HasDefaultSchema and ContextKey for Multiple Model Support" section of Julie Lerman's PluralSite video, "Entity Framework 6: Ninija Edition-What's New in EF 6" (https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/entity-framework-6-ninja-edition-whats-new/table-of-contents), it seems there is a way to run multiple schemas under a single database in Entity Framwork 6 using Code First Migrations...

However, based on the video you still need to these package manager commands for each project that houses a separate context:
1. enable-migrations
2. add-migration [MIGRATION NAME]
3. update-database

This is fine and good if you actually care about maintaining migrations going forward, which is not a concern of mine.

What I'd like to do is have each of my Context's initializers set to DropCreateDatabaseAlways, and when I start up my client app (in this case, an MVC site), code first will create the database for the first context used, create the tables in with the correct schema for that context, and then create the tables for the rest of the contexts with the correct schema.

I don't mind if the whole database is dropped and recreated every time I hit F5.

What is happening now is the last context that is accessed in the client app is the only context tables that are created in the database... any contexts being accessed before the last get their tables blown away.

I am currently using two contexts, a Billing context and a Shipping context.

Here is my code:

My client app is an MVC website, and its HomeController's Index method looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{

    List<Shipping.Customer> 
    List<Billing.Customer> billingCustomers;

    using (var shippingContext = new Shipping.ShippingContext())
    {
        shippingCustomers = shippingContext.Customers.ToList();
    }

    using (var billingContext = new Billing.BillingContext())
    {
        billingCustomers = billingContext.Customers.ToList();
    }
}
```

Here is my DbMigrationsConfigurationClass and ShippingContext class for the Shipping Context:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<ShippingContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
    }

    protected override void Seed(ShippingContext context)
    {
    }
}

public class ShippingContext : DbContext
{
    public ShippingContext() : base("MultipleModelDb")
    {
    }

    static ShippingContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new ShippingContextInitializer());
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("Shipping");
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

    class ShippingContextInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<ShippingContext>
    {
    }
}
```

Likewise, here is the DbMigrationConfiguration class for the Billing Context and the BillingContext class:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<BillingContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
    }

    protected override void Seed(BillingContext context)
    {
    }
}

public class BillingContext : DbContext
{
    public BillingContext() : base("MultipleModelDb")
    {
    }

    static BillingContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new BillingContextInitializer());
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("Billing");
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

    class BillingContextInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<BillingContext>
    {
    }
}
```

based on the order that the contexts are being called in the controller's action method, whichever context is accessed last is the only context that is created... the other context is wiped out.

I feel like what I'm trying to do is very simple, yet code first migrations, as well as trying to "shoehorn" Entity Framework to represent multiple contexts as separate schemas in the same physical database seems a bit "hacky"...

I'm not that versed with migrations to begin with, so what I'm trying to do might not make any sense at all.

Any feedback would be helpful.

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: Makes sense since each initializer drops the database. Try switching the second initializer to CreateDatabaseIfNotExists.

Comment: Thanks Steve, I'll try this when I get home tonight. Although what you're saying will work, if I end up having a bunch of DbContexts, one for each bounded context/boundary in my system I want represented by schema in one database, I'm assuming that all all my initlizers shoudl use CrateDatabaseIfNotExists... it's possible that I would not know which DbContext would be accessed first.

Comment: Since you have Pluralsight, check her other video where she describes a process where basically you create an initializer and context for the sole purpose of updating the database - you don't use this in code, you use the bounded contexts. https://app.pluralsight.com/player?course=efarchitecture&author=julie-lerman&name=efarchitecture-m2-boundedcontext&clip=11&mode=live

Comment: Steve, this will work. However, the drawback to Julie's approach is that when one project owns all DbSets across all contexts, you cannot name a DbSet<T> the same name for T. For example, if I have a Shipping boundary and Billing boundary, and each boundary has a Customer entity, the "master" DbContext used to initialize/migrate all entities across all contexts cannot both be named "Customer".

Comment: what did you end up for solution?